# create keypair object from extended object javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a regex like this:

```
    var regex = /(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d) (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d): ([^:]+): (.*)/g;
```

this a regex to read the string below and divide it up into several object properties

```
    27/02/14 23:45:01: Tom: Ja
```

With a little help of the regex above, I'm creating an object via this code:

```
var match;
while( match = regex.exec(chat)) {
     messages.push({
    date: match[1],
    time: match[2],
    name: match[3],
    message: match[4]
   });
}
```

Sometime the date doesn't look like `dd/mm/yy` but rather like `dd-mm-yyyy` or `dd-mm-yy`.

Whichever is the good match I want to parse that into the `date` property. but when adding multiple regex to match[1] the code seems to fail.

Comment: So what are you asking for? An expression that matches `dd/mm/yy`, `dd-mm-yyyy` and `dd-mm-yy`?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, your code works when the date is always formatted the same, and you want to be able to accept different formats of dates.

Try this:

```
var regex = /(\d\d[\/-]\d\d[\/-]\d{2,4}) (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d): ([^:]+): (.*)/g;
```

The above regular expression should accept either a forward slash or dash (by saying `[\/-]`), and then for the year, accept 2 or 4 digits (by saying `\d{2,4}`).

**Edit**

A commenter below made a good suggestion.  If you want to make sure the delimiter is the same in both cases, you can do this instead:

```
var regex = /(\d\d([\/-])\d\d\2\d{2,4}) (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d): ([^:]+): (.*)/g;
```

Just take note, though, that the first delimiter is now a match, so you'll have to adjust your code that creates your object. `match[2]` will now be the delimiter, so you'll have to do something like this:

```
var match;
while( match = regex.exec(chat)) {
    messages.push({
        date: match[1],
        time: match[3],
        name: match[4],
        message: match[5]
   });
}
```

Comment: Technically this would match `dd/mm-yy` as well (even though such input is probably very unlikely). To match the same delimiter in both cases, you could use a capture group and a backreference instead: `(\d\d([\/-])\d\d\2\d{2,4})` (but then the rest of the code would have to be adjusted as well).

Comment: I don't know if it's the regex, but this seems to return an empty array. If the date format is dd/mm/yy it does return a proper one.